# Is a simple and solvable group cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is not enough with the simple hypothesis?
If $g\neq e$ then $\{e\}\neq \left\langle g \right\rangle$, also $\left\langle g \right\rangle$ is a normal subgroups of $G$. If $G$ is a simple group, and $\left\langle g \right\rangle$ is not the identity therefor $G=\left\langle g \right\rangle$ thus $G$ is cyclic.
I don't see where is the solvable needed, or what my mistake is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nah [there are simple groups that are not cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups#Statement_of_the_classification_theorem). The flaw in your argument is that it's not necessarily true that a cyclic subgroup $\langle g \rangle$ is normal in the group.

Proving the claim in your titles comes down to unraveling definitions. If you have a simple group $G$, then $G$ only has a composition series $\{e\} \hookrightarrow G$. But if $G$ is solvable, then by definition $G/\{e\} \cong G$ must be abelian. Since $G$ is abelian *any* subgroup $\langle g \rangle$ must be normal, but since $G$ is simple $\langle g \rangle$ can't be a proper subgroup, so $G = \langle g \rangle$ is cyclic.

Comment: Indeed, it must be cyclic of prime order (or trivial).